# I am developing employee payroll calculation, but it shows an error for Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim hr As Integer
Dim pf As Integer
Dim da As Integer
Dim ta As Integer
Dim net As Integer

 hr = Val((TextBox1.Text * 5.5) / 100)
 pf = Val((TextBox1.Text * 10.5) / 100)
 da = Val((TextBox1.Text * 6) / 100)
 ta = Val((TextBox1.Text * 3.5) / 100)

TextBox2.Visible = True
TextBox3.Visible = True
  TextBox4.Visible = True
 TextBox5.Visible = True
  TextBox6.Visible = True

   TextBox2.Text = hr
  TextBox3.Text = pf
   TextBox4.Text = da
  TextBox5.Text = ta

 net = Val(TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text + TextBox4.Text) - Val(TextBox3.Text + TextBox5.Text)

TextBox6.Text = CLng(net)

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give some values on which the error happens. And on what line?

Comment: What's the value of textbox1 you're giving?

Answer (score 1):

While @Nadeem_MK answer is correct, there are other problems with your solution:

- you are using double for employee income. I think decimal would be a better choice since you are working with financial data and doubles are notoriously imprecise at small values.
- You are simply throwing strings (text) and doubles together - this is a recipe for hard to find bugs. Do yourself a favour and activate Option Strict on - you have more work to do, but the code will have much less errors. Informations: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329/de
- There is a risk with your Statements like "TextBox1.Text * 5.5" - if the user enters say "A" the code instantly crashes because "A" is no convertible to double. Use something like Double. TryParse to only accept valid numbers and display an error message if it's not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type of you local variable to **double**;

```
Dim hr As Double
Dim pf As Double
Dim da As Double
Dim ta As Double
Dim net As Double
```

It should normally work fine.

Comment: am given basic salary 10000 it calculate hr,pf,da and tax is correctly. but it display the net salary is 9999999000008 something  how to solve that problem friend

Comment: How did you get that? I've done a simulation of your code here and getting the following result: `hr=550.0, pf=1050.0, da=600.0, ta=350.0 and net=9750`

Answer (score 0):

It is 2013, Option Strict or not, this is what your code should look like.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim hr As Double
    Dim pf As Double
    Dim da As Double
    Dim ta As Double
    Dim net As Double

    hr = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 5.5) / 100
    pf = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 10.5) / 100
    da = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 6) / 100
    ta = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 3.5) / 100

    TextBox2.Visible = True
    TextBox3.Visible = True
    TextBox4.Visible = True
    TextBox5.Visible = True
    TextBox6.Visible = True

    TextBox2.Text = CStr(hr)
    TextBox3.Text = CStr(pf)
    TextBox4.Text = CStr(da)
    TextBox5.Text = CStr(ta)

    Dim net As Double = (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) + hr + da) - (pf + ta)

    TextBox6.Text = CStr(net)
End Sub
```